# mule datamapper to convert soap request

Tags: mule, datamapper

I have a Mule Batch flow where I am using datamapper in input phase to convert a collection of POJOs to SAS Objects. The batch flow is triggered from another flow which accepts a SOAP request and converts to a list of POJO objects. I'm wondering if I can skip the first conversion (SOAP request to a list of POJO) and use Datamapper to directly convert SOAP request to the expected SAS objects.

```
<data-mapper:config name="Xml_users__To_List_SASUser" transformationGraphPath="Xml_users__to_list_sasuser.grf"/>

<flow name="mainFlow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9002" path="updateUsers" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <batch:execute name="userUpdateBatch" doc:name="userUpdateBatch"/>
</flow>

<batch:job name="userUpdateBatch" max-failed-records="5">
        <batch:input>
            <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Xml_users__To_List_SASUser"/>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</batch:input>
```

The script looks like below

```
//MEL
//START -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.__id = input.__id;
//END -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.LastName = input.lastName;
```

Comment: Please check the new Dataweave for such features

Comment: Load your xsd  ( soap request) in input phase of the datamapper  and select the pojo in output end. DataMapper is deprecated in 3.7+. Opt for dataweaver.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have 3.7 yet. We have 3.6.2 EE...so...datamapper is the choice.

Comment: For some reason, when I map the XML to POJO (SAS)....I get an empty arraylist! Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Could you post snippet of code which you tried, xml and SAS object structure.

Comment: Pasted the code snippet. At the logger after datamapper:transform, the payload is []